# What is the difference between a lacquer polish and a varnish

Tags: woodworking

I have got this bottle of wood polish (an Indian brand called sheenlac). I also later got Varnish (PU). Are both required to be applied after sanding or just the wood polish would do ?

Comment: The [product page](http://sheenlac.com/sheenlac-wood-fillers-polish.html) (if I got the right one) states the polish is just a top coat, and the wood needs to be sealed prior to application.

Answer (score 4):

Wood polish is usually an oil, wax, or oil and wax treatment. Waxes include carnauba, parrafin, beeswav etc.; oils could be tung oil, linseed oil, mineral oil, petroleum oils, or oils from animal fats. Polishes help protect wood but are different from varnish. Varnish (whether natural or synthetic) create a fairly hard and durable surface coating, which could then be maintained by periodically applying a polish.

Answer (score -1):

polish is a basic treatment used to enhance to beauty of wood grains of wood and protect wood. While, varnish is protective transparent coat applied after polish as a maintenance coat after some period.

Comment: This is the same as the other answer posted.  Duplicate answers are usually deleted.

Comment: No, actually, it's backwards, saying polish then varnish, so it's just wrong...